# React-Native. Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import {
    Image,
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ListView,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

import ViewContainer from '../../components/ViewContainer';
import StatusbarBackground from "../../components/StatusbarBackground";
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Comments extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
            comment: '',
            post: '',
        }

        this.componentDidMount();

        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount(this);
        this.listenForItems = this.listenForItems.bind(this);
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);

        this._comment = this._comment.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('/comments')              
        this.listenForItems(commentsRef);
    }

    listenForItems(commentsRef) {
        var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref('/comments')
        commentsRef.on('value', snap => {
          var items = [];
          snap.forEach((child) => {
              if(child.val().post == this.state.post){
                items.push({
                  post: child.val().post,
                  email: child.val().email,
                  comment: child.val().comment,
                  uid: child.key
                });
              }
          });

          var temp = []
          var len = items.length;
          for (var i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            temp.push(items[i]);
          }
          items = temp;

          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
          });
        });
    }

    _comment(post) {
        var commentRef = firebase.database().ref('/comments');
        var curr = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;

        var newComment = commentRef.push();
        newComment.set({
            'post': post,
            'email': curr,
            'comment': this.state.comment,
        });
    }

    renderItem(item) {      
        return (
          <TouchableHighlight>
            <View style={styles.post}>
              <Text style={styles.email}>{item.email}{' said:'}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{item.comment}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.line}></Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }

    render() {

        this.state.post = this.props.post

        return (
            <ViewContainer>
                <StatusbarBackground />

                <Image style={styles.title} 
                                source={require('../../images/comment.png')}
                            />

                <TextInput 
                    style={styles.textinput} 
                    multiline={true}
                    placeholder = "Write something..."
                    onChangeText={(comment) => this.setState({comment: comment})}
                    value={this.state.comment}
                    placeholderTextColor = 'black'
                    underlineColorAndroid = 'white'
                    autoCorrect = {false}
                />

                <View style={styles.comment}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._comment(this.props.post)}}>
                            <Text>Publish</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ListView
                      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                      renderRow={this.renderItem} />
                </View>

            </ViewContainer>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm making a social app with posts, likes and comments. When I want to see the comments of a post I'm rendering a list view with all the comments. The first try it works but if I want to see the comments of other post I get this error.

I think I have to use **componentWillUnmount()** but idk what code I have to put there. Any ideias? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this.componentDidMount() from your constructor, and remove the line where you bind it. It is called automatically in the React component lifecycle, which is available because you extend Component.

You should also have the componentWillUnmount function that should call something like:

`this.commentsRef.off(...)`

In order to remove the listener. In order to do that correctly, move the commentsRef callback to its own class function (call it onCommentsRefValue or something), and then you can do `this.commentsRef.on('value', this.onCommentsRefValue )` and subsequently in componentWillUnmount you can call `this.commentsRef.off('value', this.onCommentsRefValue )`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Sure will help :)

Comment: @rafaelqfigueiredo I have updated the answer with more information